# JDBC Return results via writer to client program?

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to return a mySQL result to my client program. I think its not connecting as I can return the connection error, but I believe all the settings to be correct, and have used them before on a PHP connection?

Here's the full code which totally works if you just want to return a String:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TestDatabase extends HttpServlet {

    private static String message = "Error during Servlet processing";
    private static String inputStream;
    ResultSet rs;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        try {
            int len = req.getContentLength();
            byte[] input = new byte[len];

            ServletInputStream sin = req.getInputStream();
            int c, count = 0;
            while ((c = sin.read(input, count, input.length - count)) != -1) {
                count += c;
            }

            sin.close();
            String inString = new String(input);
            int index = inString.indexOf("=");
            String value = inString.substring(index + 1);
            inputStream = URLDecoder.decode(value, "UTF-8");

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        try {
            responseWriter(resp);
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }// end of requestReader

    public void responseWriter(HttpServletResponse resp) throws SQLException {



        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://server.co.uk:port/dbName?user=UserName&password=PassWord");

            Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable;");

        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("fail");
        }

        while (rs.next()){
            String output = rs.getString("column_name");
        }

        try {
            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
            resp.getOutputStream());
            writer.write(output);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

    }// end of responseWriter

}// end of class
```

EDIT: Its throwing a ClassNotFoundException I believe.

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do that _doesn't_ work.

Comment: I believe that it is not connecting, yet my input data which is not shown is correct. I was wondering if there was an error in my code elsewhere causing it to fail to connect?

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: Its throwing ClassNotFoundException?

Comment: Please add more info. When you call the Servlet by url this shows you the ClassNotFoundException? Have you checked if the jar of the MySQL JDBC is in your WEB-INF\lib folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In public void doPost() method you are not throwing 
throws SQLException , IOException